# Polars: Pad list columns to specific size

Tags: python, python-polars

I think i ran into the XY problem...

Here is what i actually want to do:

To be exact i have a dataframe like:

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────┬───────┬──────────────────────────┐
│ nrs       ┆ stuff ┆ more_stuff               │
│ ---       ┆ ---   ┆ ---                      │
│ list[i64] ┆ i64   ┆ list[list[i64]]          │
╞═══════════╪═══════╪══════════════════════════╡
│ [1, 2, 3] ┆ 1     ┆ [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]] │
│ [2, 4]    ┆ 2     ┆ [[4, 4], [5, 5]]         │
│ [1]       ┆ 3     ┆ [[6, 6]]                 │
└───────────┴───────┴──────────────────────────┘
```

With normal int64 columns, list[int64] columns and one list[list[64]] column.
I want to be able to specify a size and set the length of all the list (also the nested) columns to that size. Either by shortening to that size or by padding them with their last value (`list[-1]` for normal python lists) for both the nested and the normal lists. The non-list columns should be left unchanged.

So the result for N=2 for the above dataframe should be:

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────┬───────┬──────────────────┐
│ nrs       ┆ stuff ┆ more_stuff       │
│ ---       ┆ ---   ┆ ---              │
│ list[i64] ┆ i64   ┆ list[list[i64]]  │
╞═══════════╪═══════╪══════════════════╡
│ [1, 2]    ┆ 1     ┆ [[1, 1], [2, 2]] │
│ [2, 4]    ┆ 2     ┆ [[4, 4], [5, 5]] │
│ [1, 1]    ┆ 3     ┆ [[6, 6], [6, 6]] │
└───────────┴───────┴──────────────────┘
```

Comment: It's probably a good idea to change the question title to better reflect your updated example as it's specifically about padding list columns. You could also remove the reindex/pandas part as it's no longer relevant.

Comment: @jqurious thanks. I didnt realize one could update the title. Been using reddit too much.

Answer (score 1):

Answer via [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/13u6bha/padshorten_polars_dataframe_to_a_given_size/jlzpz7m/) from /u/commandlineluser

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
   "nrs": [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4], [1]], 
   "stuff": [1, 2, 3], 
   "more_stuff": [[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]], [[4, 4], [5, 5]], [[6, 6]]]
})

cols = "nrs", "more_stuff"

df.with_columns(
   pl.col(cols).arr.take(
      pl.arange(0, pl.col(cols).arr.lengths().max()), 
      null_on_oob=True
   ).arr.eval(pl.element().forward_fill())
)

# shape: (3, 3)
# ┌───────────┬───────┬──────────────────────────┐
# │ nrs       ┆ stuff ┆ more_stuff               │
# │ ---       ┆ ---   ┆ ---                      │
# │ list[i64] ┆ i64   ┆ list[list[i64]]          │
# ╞═══════════╪═══════╪══════════════════════════╡
# │ [1, 2, 3] ┆ 1     ┆ [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]] │
# │ [2, 4, 4] ┆ 2     ┆ [[4, 4], [5, 5], [5, 5]] │
# │ [1, 1, 1] ┆ 3     ┆ [[6, 6], [6, 6], [6, 6]] │
# └───────────┴───────┴──────────────────────────┘
```

You can add a `.slice()/.head()` to pad them to a smaller length.

**EDIT:**

Possibly worth noting that `.forward_fill()` doesn't specifically target the padded nulls, so that could be an issue if there were nulls in the initial data. It's possible to handle this, but requires a bit more code.

Answer (score 0):

See [`extend_constant`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.extend_constant.html#polars-expr-extend-constant).

You can shorten with `head` / `tail`

Comment: That doesnt seem to allow me to easily pad with the last value in the columns.

And to pad to a given size i guess i could extend by that size and then take the head of that size since i dont know how much to pad but only to what size.